# www not working sometimes, but http always active

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, virtualhost

I have a centos5 server setup with apache and vhosts.

I bought a domain and had it redirected to my servers IP.

my HTTP is always active, however if I call up my http://www.... then I find it does not always work...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to DNS or your server.

- To check the DNS: nslookup YOUDOMAIN
- To check server: telnet YOUIP 80 To
- chech both: telnet YOUDOMAIN 80

Comment: nslookup http://www.my-site.com/
;; reply from unexpected source: 84.246.88.10#53, expected 192.168.55.1#53
;; reply from unexpected source: 84.246.88.10#53, expected 192.168.55.1#53
Server:  84.246.88.10
Address: 84.246.88.10#53

** server can't find http://www.my-site.com/: NXDOMAIN